# ASP.NET application using the wrong file path when publishing to a windows server 2008 machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an asp.net application that i am modifying. I setup visual studio 2010 to publish to are development server which is running windows server 2008 RC 2 (dont think it matters).  I added a new webform to the application through visual studios "add new item" feature and it works on my local computer.  When i publish to the server, it starts to throw cryptographic exceptions because its trying to access a .p12 file in order to send apple push notifications to an iphone device.  I thought it was something wrong with the certificate at first so i added print statements to the code and noticed it is trying to access the new page at the file path on my local machine instead of the file path on the server.  Does anyone have any ideas on why its doing that?  Is there a way to make the file path relative to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use MapPath("{relativePath/FileName}") .  This will return a physical path.

```
filename = MapPath("/images/logo.jpg")
```

Would something along the lines of "C:\inetpub\webroot\images\logo.jpg"

Comment: the file path for the certificate is fine. The filepath for the actual webpage is wrong.  I have it print the stack trace for the exception and it says the problem is at C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\myapp\newpage.aspx line: 71  when it should say C:\inetpub\wwwroot\newpage.aspx line: 71

Comment: Actually the stack trace is correct, as it is showing the path to the file where it was when it was compiled, as this information is stored in the .pdb file which was generated during the build. So it is actually running from c:\inetpub\wwwroot\newpage.aspx on your server, but the stack trace will show the location where the file was when it was compiled.

Comment: oohh ok. do you have any other ideas on why its getting a cryptographic error on the server but not on my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

Server does not matter. The file was added with an absolute path. Not sure why and don't have the time to research.

How is the site set up on your debug machine? Are you using IIS or the ASP.NET development server? Not sure if this makes a big deal, but switching to IIS and better mimicking production often solves these little snit type of errors. To switch, add the folder to IIS, then remove the project and re-include with the HTTP path instead of the project folder.

If local IIS is not an option, or you already have done that, I would do a search for the path in question and alter it there. If you find no results, this could we be embedded in the solution file some how.

Comment: on my local machine it is setup to use asp.net dev server. I'll try to switch it to iis.

Comment: It certainly helps when you are trying to figure out disparities between local and production.

Comment: Same problem.  it worked on my machine but not the server.  I think it does have something to do with the certificate..im not sure what though since it works on my machine...

Comment: @MBU: Are you also using the ASP.NET development server? And, have you checked to see if the path is "hard coded", implicitly (by the tool) or explicitly (you did it somehow)? Both are the proper troubleshooting steps to take.

Comment: figured out that the problem wasnt the path. It has something to so with the certificates.  When i run under asp.net dev server everything works fine.  but when i switch to iis it doesn't it gives a cryptographicexception error. are there differences in the way certificates are being read when running under iis?